# Increment the counter each time someone connect to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

Guys I have the following code which it supposed to increment a counter each time some one connect to server and post the message in the console but it increments only one time ,can you help me?

```
'use strict'
//Require express
var express=require('express');
//Trigger express
var app=express();
var counter=0;
//Set up the route URL
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send("<h1>You have connected</h1>");
});

//set up the port
app.listen(3000,function(){

//increment counter

  counter+=1;
  console.log("you have connected " + counter + " times");
})
```

Comment: Are you connecting to the route on port 3000, or just the express route on `/`.

Comment: I am connecting to port 3000 and the route is / it could be anythink like /home or /dog or /blabla

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your counter to inside the response.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  counter++;
  res.send("<h1>You have connected "+counter+ " times </h1>");
});
```

This way whenever the page is loaded it will increment, not just when you boot it up and start listening with app.listen().

Answer (score 1):

- listen callback is called only once, when the server starts listening.
- No need of persistence of variable, as long as your server is alive.
- placing counter inside app.get() block will work only for clients connecting to route '/'.

Ideally, you would need to add a listener to the 'connect' event (express object inherits from HTTP, so the server has this event) of the server, and increment the counter over there:

```
app.on('connect', function() {
  counter++;
});
```

Hoe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to store the counter variable in some persistant storage like a database or a textfile otherwise it will always be set to zero on each request

Comment: local storage would work on the client side. Are you using a database (mongoDB, postgreSQL, etc?)

Comment: so I have to use a database and save the counter there and after to parse it from there and post in console?

Comment: Yes, That would be the only way for the data to persist and for all users to see the count. Even if you were to use localStorage on the client side, it would only show logins for that specific users. If 2 users were viewing your web page, user A would not be able to see how many times user B logged in and posted a message. If you stored logins in the DB, all user's could see the number of logins. I'd recommend going through a nodeJS + mongoDB or nodeJS + postgres tutorial.